# Python: Need help creating an Intraday 1m tick OHLC Chart

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I am pretty much brand new to all things python, and much to my chagrin I have been trying to produce a fairly straight forward OHLC chart. Code below with dataframe samples.
I am trying to plot and save an OHLC chart, for a single stock, on a single trading day, in 1m ticks. The yaxis appears to working fine, however the chart when shown is blank. The xaxis is showing the starting time of 09:30 but with no other 1m ticks. Moving the chart over the blank figure shows values for the yaxis but the x= nada.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hUmb.jpg)

What I am hoping to eventually achieve, is the xaxis label to show the time, in minutes, no dae required, 90 degrees rotated, at say 15min intervals. I would rather an OHLC chart than a candlestick, but I also want it to be decipherable, as I have seen many versions that are just a blur of tiny vertical lines that are no use to anyone. If the size needs to be stretched horizontally in order to fit the some 376 1m records in the dataframe, then so be it. If it is too cluttered then I would like to be able to space out the tick interval perhaps to every 2 or 5 mins. The xaxis xticks should still remain at 15min intervals however. I would like to then save the result as a jpg.

I have tried so many variations of mplfinace,  now no longer know what is the most recent of valid module. I have tried both 'quotes' and values in the candlestick_ohlc statement, there seems to be no apparent difference. I have read and re-read and tried so many examples but all seems to fail at the translation of the time in all things to do with the xaxis and it is very confusing for me to understand and beyond frustrating .. heh.

If anyone could kindly point me in the right direction here I would be very grateful for any and all assistance.

Many thanks, Tim.D

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc

sym = sys.argv[1] #symbol in all caps
run_dt = sys.argv[2] #run date of the required process requires the date to be surrounded by 'quotes'
run_int = sys.argv[2].replace('/', '-')
run_int = run_int.replace("'", "")

import pyodbc #database connectivity
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(dsn='abc', user='abc', password='abc', autocommit=False)

df = pd.read_sql_query(" \
    SELECT TIMESTAMP(ACT_DATE||' '||TIME(TICK)) AS TIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE \
    FROM INTRADAY_IDX \
    WHERE ACT_DATE = "+run_dt+" \
    AND SYMBOL = '"+sym+"' \
    ORDER BY 1",cnxn, )

print(df)
```

This produces a dataframe as follows:

TIME    OPEN    HIGH     LOW   CLOSE

0   2021-02-12 09:30:00  314.27  314.50  314.22  314.49

1   2021-02-12 09:31:00  314.51  314.73  314.44  314.63

2   2021-02-12 09:32:00  314.63  314.79  314.54  314.73

..                  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...

375 2021-02-12 15:59:00  315.01  315.14  314.85  315.00

376 2021-02-12 16:00:00  315.00  315.18  314.97  315.18

```
df.TIME = mdates.date2num(df.TIME.dt.to_pydatetime())
print(df.head(5))
```

TIME    OPEN    HIGH     LOW   CLOSE

0  737833.395833  314.27  314.50  314.22  314.49

1  737833.396528  314.51  314.73  314.44  314.63

2  737833.397222  314.63  314.79  314.54  314.73

3  737833.397917  314.83  314.89  314.76  314.85

...

```
#quotes = [tuple(x) for x in df[['TIME', 'OPEN', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'CLOSE']].to_records(index=False)]
#print(quotes)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,7)) 

plt.yscale('linear') #default scaling of the y axis

ax.set_xlim('09:30', '16:00') #sets the start and end values for the xaxis charting
start, end = ax.get_xlim() #initializes the start and end variables
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, 1800)) #sets the tick values for charting
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=12) #sets the rotation value of the x axis ticks
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)

ax.set_title(sym+' OHLC Intraday Chart', fontsize=14, fontweight = 'bold')
ax.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=12, fontweight = 'bold')
ax.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=12, fontweight = 'bold')

plt.tight_layout() #reduces the space padding surrounding the graph

ax.grid(True)

candlestick_ohlc(ax, df.values, width = 1/(24*60*2.5), alpha = 1.0, colorup = 'g', colordown ='r')
#candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width = 1/(24*60*2.5), alpha = 1.0, colorup = 'g', colordown ='r')

bbox_inches='tight') #saves the data to to jpg file
#plt.savefig('c:\\temp\\charts\\'+sym+'_OHLC_'+run_int+'.jpg', format='jpg', quality=95, #plt.close()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of this function must be an array. Also, the format of the date and time must be converted to `mdates2num()`. The rest of the time, the date and time are controlled using a locator and a formatter. I think `ax.set_xlim('09:30', '16:00')` related in your code is the cause of the error. The data acquisition is from Yahoo Finance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
import yfinance as yf

dia = yf.download("DIA", period='1d', interval='1m', start="2021-02-11", end='2021-02-12')

df = dia.copy()
df.index = mdates.date2num(df.index)
data = df.reset_index().values

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,7)) 

sym = 'DIA'
candlestick_ohlc(ax, data, width=1/(24*60*2.5), alpha=1.0, colorup='g', colordown='r')

ax.set_title(sym+' OHLC Intraday Chart', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
# update start
ax.set_xlim(data[0][0], data[382][0])
ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax1.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks())
ax1.set_ybound(ax.get_ybound())
ax1.set_yticklabels([str(x) for x in ax.get_yticks()])
# update end
ax.grid()

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(locator))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

and thanks for much for the response. Using your code I have managed to get it working now, also adding a secondary plot. Code below:

```
import sys, os, time, warnings #csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
#import numpy as np
#from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
#from matplotlib import dates, ticker
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc

sym = sys.argv[1] #symbol in all caps
run_dt = sys.argv[2] #run date of the required process requires the date to be surrounded by 'quotes'
run_int = sys.argv[2].replace('/', '-') #reformat the date
run_int = run_int.replace("'", "") #reformat the date

import pyodbc #database connectivity
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(dsn='abc', user='abc', password='abc', autocommit=False)

db = pd.read_sql_query(" \
    SELECT timestamp(ACT_DATE||' '||TIME(TICK)) AS TIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE \
    FROM SQ4_INTRADAY_IDX \
    WHERE ACT_DATE = "+run_dt+" \
    AND SYMBOL = '"+sym+"' \
    ORDER BY 1",cnxn, )

print(db)
db['TIME']= pd.to_datetime(db['TIME'])
db.set_index('TIME', inplace=True) #this resets the dataframe index to the time values
#db.info() #shows column data types

#setup an array for the candlestick chart
dd = db.copy() #create a copy of the dataframe
dd.index = mdates.date2num(dd.index) #set the datetime to numeric for the chart to work
dd_data = dd.reset_index().values #set the index
#print(dd_data)

clse = db["CLOSE"] #setup the data for plotting an additional subplot line

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,7))

ax.set_title(sym+' OHLC Intraday Chart', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')

candlestick_ohlc(ax, dd_data, width=.0003, alpha=.8, colorup='g', colordown='r')
ax.plot(clse, color = 'k', linestyle='--', linewidth = .5, label='Close')

plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=12) #sets the rotation value of the x axis ticks
plt.yticks(fontsize=12) #sets the rotation value of the x axis ticks

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=30))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

plt.tight_layout() #reduces the space padding surrounding the graph
plt.savefig('c:\\temp\\'+sym+'_OHLC Intrday Chart for '+run_int+'.jpg', format='jpg', quality=95, bbox_inches='tight') #saves the data to to jpg file

plt.show()
```

This produces the attached chart.[image: Chart]
My issue is that I am trying to remove the padded space between the left and right y-axis scales. In other words I would like the 9:30 label to appear directly under the left and 16:00 under the right margins. Basically I guess I am trying to stretch the chart to fill the entire chart box.

Also is there anyway to add the left Price scale values to both the left and right sides ?

Thanks for assist, much appreciated.
Regards, Tim.D

Comment: Please refer to my response for the code that implements the requirements added in the self-answer.